# Chef paste string in file for each number 1...5

Tags: ruby, templates, foreach, chef-infra

I have a template.

```
/path/to/script attribute >> /path/to/log
```

Need to add to a file that string from a template with "attribute" is numers, lets say, from 1 to 5.

```
/path/to/script 1 >> /path/to/log
/path/to/script 2 >> /path/to/log
/path/to/script 3 >> /path/to/log
/path/to/script 4 >> /path/to/log
/path/to/script 5 >> /path/to/log
```

How can i do that, comrads?

Thx in advance.

P.S. "attribute" will be an item in data bag.

Comment: Which chef? Not the esoteric language?

Comment: @minseong It's [OpsCode Chef](https://www.getchef.com/chef/).

Comment: how can i put 1..5 in chef node attribute?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erb just uses standard Ruby code for loops so:

```
<%- (1..5).each do |n| -%>
/path/to/script <%= n %> >> /path/to/log
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: thx, m8, and if i need to paste an data bag item there?.. and how an item must look like?

Comment: In a role? `default_attributes :foo => (1..5)`

Comment: `<%- node['attribute'].each do |n| -%>
/path/to/script <%= n %> >> /path/to/log
<%- end -%>`                                                       can i do like that?..

Comment: i have several attributes in `default_attribute` section, and knife don't allow me to save role `lexical error: invalid char in json text.`

Comment: If you are using the JSON format you will need to expand the array yourself (and use correct JSON formatting).

Comment: i added `"attribue": [1,2,3,4,5],` it works, but it only created 5 strings without pasting attribute in..

Comment: It's a template, add what you want.

Comment: it paste stings like this `/path/to/script >> /path/to/log`

Comment: If you would like more interactive help, I would recommend asking in the #chef IRC channel. At this point it sounds like are you confused about how to use roles and attributes.

Comment: My bad, m8. I make a syntax mistake, all works fine))